# I keep repeatedly getting the same result from code

Tags: c++

Supposed to 'spin" fruit like a slot machine I suppose and output what fruit is on the screen, for some reason it's only giving me apple even though my randomSpin integer does change. I've tried stepping through the code but am not sure exactly what I'm looking for, for some reason it is also giving me w1.spin, w2.spin, and w3.spin as the same number (for randomSpin) when I'm stepping through it.

```
class Cspinner
{
private:

    int randomSpin;
    string FruitName;

    int apple;
    int orange;
    int cherry;
    int banana;
    int peach;

public:
    Cspinner()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    apple = 30;
    orange = 25;
    cherry = 20;
    banana = 15;
    peach = 10;
}

    Cspinner(int newapple, int neworange, int newcherry, int newbanana, int newpeach)
    {
        randomSpin = 0;
        apple = newapple; //set apple to new value
        orange = neworange; //set orange to new value
        cherry = newcherry; //set cherry to new value
        banana = newbanana; //set banana to new value
        peach = newpeach; //set peach to new value

        srand(time(NULL));
    }


    void spin()
    {
        randomSpin = rand() % 100 + 1;

        if ((randomSpin >= 1) && (randomSpin <= apple))
        {
            FruitName = "apple ";
        }
        else if ((randomSpin > apple) && (randomSpin <= orange))
        {
            FruitName = "orange ";
        }
        else if ((randomSpin > orange) && (randomSpin <= cherry))
        {
            FruitName = "cherry ";
        }
        else if ((randomSpin > cherry) && (randomSpin <= banana))
        {
            FruitName = "banana ";
        }
        else if ((randomSpin > banana) && (randomSpin <= peach))
        {
            FruitName = "peach ";
        }
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << FruitName;
    }

};


void main()
{
    Cspinner w1;
    Cspinner w2;
    Cspinner w3(80, 5, 5, 5, 5);
    for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        w1.spin();
        w2.spin();
        w3.spin();
        w1.show();
        w2.show();
        w3.show();
        cout << endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant for those integers to be percentages, make them cumulative. For the orange's cutoff, use the sum of apple and orange as you have them now. For cherry, the sum of the first three (apple, orange, and cherry). If you want the user to be able to enter percentages, express this process in the function you're using to set the thresholds (the Cspinner constructor).

Comment: It is supposed to be percentages, but it's supposed to be in a way that is like a spinning top or something, so 1-30 is apple 31-56 is orange, etc. How would I go about doing that then?

Also I need it so people can edit what the %'s are such as in the w3 in the main form, so I can't just change it to static numbers unfortunately.

Comment: Just as you said. Use 30 for apple, 56 for orange, etc. You can get the threshold for orange by adding its percentage to apple. Get cherry's threshold by adding apple, orange, and cherry. Or you can think of it as adding each fruit's percentage to the previous fruit's threshold.

Comment: Okay, but I can't use static numbers such as 30, 56, etc. So could I just do peach,   else if ((randomSpin > peach) && (randomSpin <= peach+banana)) ?

Comment: Exactly. Or you could store the sums instead of having to compute them each time. Up to you.

Comment: so use a temp variable to store the sums?

Comment: If it were, me, I wouldn't even bother storing the raw percentages, since you know they just get added together later. But yeah, a temp variable would look much nicer than having those long sums.

Answer (score 0):

The value of apple is greater than all the other values.  Yet you are checking it first.  The only two possible outcomes are apple or nothing